# Custom Suitelet as the landing page for the vendor center role

Tags: netsuite

How can I add a custom suitelet as the landing page in the vendor center for a role ? I tried to add the suitelet in the custom role's preferences list, but my suitelet form is not available over there ? How to make a suitelet page available as the landing page for vendor center ?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to add a suitelet as the landing page, but you could wrap the same functionality in a portlet and add it to the dashboard. You can then publish the dashboard and make it available as the default dashboard/landing for a role.